# GridView is not working inside SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

I have a Column and inside that Column, I have SingleChildScrollView and inside it I have another Column. This is not working:

```
  Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SliderWidget(SliderList, "text", "text"),
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              text("Some text"),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                  child:
                      GridListing(FavouriteList, false),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Please suggest me alternate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SingleChildScrollView` and `Expanded` both are trying to get infinite height.  Providing height on `GridView` will solve the issue.

To understand the overflow, we need to check how `SingleChildScrollView` is getting size and setting on children. In order to get available space, we need wrap `SingleChildScrollView` with `Expanded` widget.

Now we can wrap `GridView` with `SizedBox(height:x`

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) => Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        // SliderWidget(SliderList, "text", "text"),
        const SizedBox(height: 20),
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text("Some text"),
                SizedBox(
                  height: constraints.maxHeight * .6,
                  child: GridView.count(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 4,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 4,
                    children: List.generate(
                      222,
                      (index) => Container(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        width: 200,
                        height: 200,
                        child: Text(" $index"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 500,
                  color: Colors.pink,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

A better way of doing it will be using CustomScrollView

Answer (score 0):

If you use the **IntrinsicHeight** widget around the inner column flutter can display your widget tree.

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    SliderWidget(SliderList, "text", "text"),
    const SizedBox(height: 20),
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: IntrinsicHeight( // added widget
        child: Column(
          children: [
            text("Some text"),
            Expanded(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                child:
                    GridListing(FavouriteList, false),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: It's not working. Same